# How would I customize the button link of print pdf in the library ReactToPrint?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-to-pdf

[Here is the code from sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-to-print-rzdhd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

So how would I put the link button `Print this out!` under the table? 
could I customize it according to my own design by using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write it under the table component would be good enough

```
<div>
  <ComponentToPrint ref={el => (this.componentRef = el)} />
  <ReactToPrint
    trigger={() => <a href="#">Print this out!</a>}
    content={() => this.componentRef}
  />
</div>
```

[image]